# How Do You Configure Spring MVC @PathVariables to Accept Strings Containing Dashes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Given the following request mapping on a Spring MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=GET, value="/users/{name}")
ModelAndView findUser(@PathVariable String name) {
    ...
}
```

How can I make it accept a `@PathVariable` with a dash in it?

The following works, passing in `fred` as the name:

```
GET /users/fred
```

However the following does not work, passing in `null` in place of the name:

```
GET /users/u-fred
```

I would appreciate suggestions on how to define the `@PathVariable` so it can accept dashed strings, for example, `u-fred`.

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious... do you have somesort of `@InitBinder` that will cause this problem? A string with dash(es) in it works fine for me, I use it a lot in my projects.

Comment: Dashes and underscores are perfectly legal characters if URL encoding is not used. I suppose you could do {foo}-{bar} and have 2 params, but that is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested that with my spring-mvc 3.0.5 application and it works fine with a dash:

- make sure you are running the latest version
- make sure you are tracking the correct request (and not some fake one, for example a forgotten ajax request)

Comment: Thanks. I want a variable containing a dash ("-") not a slash ("/"). I am on the latest version of Spring and am doing straight HTTP calls (no ajax, etc.).

Comment: @SingleShot - sorry, a typo - I tried with a _dash_ and it worked.

Comment: Yes, spring-mvc 3.0.5 works with dash. I have just tested it two days ago.

Comment: Yep I can verify that too. One of our applications uses dashes in every request.

Comment: This also works fine for me. I was very confused by the 404 page I was receiving until I worked out that I had forgotten to add `@ResponseBody` to my method signature. I was mistaking a 404 for Spring failing to find my method. Just adding this in case anyone is doing a similarly idiotic thing.